# Error 8120 in T-SQL (nested select command)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is my mistake in this statement?

```
Select Max (TBLvirtual.c2) as MOF --> Most ordered food (MOF)--//
      ,TBLvirtual.c1
from
    (select a.OrdItems as c1, count(a.OrdID) as c2
     from Orderrouter a 
     group by a.OrdItems) as TBLvirtual
```

I received this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column 'TBLvirtual.c1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner Group By for count has already made C1 unique so there is no need doing aggregate on them for MAX. Do this

```
 select a.OrdItems as c1, count(a.OrdID) as c2
 from Orderrouter a 
 group by a.OrdItems
 order by count(a.OrdID) desc
```

That will give you the highest count first followed by the next. If you want top 1 or top N, do

```
Select TOP 1 c1, c2 FROM
(
 select a.OrdItems as c1, count(a.OrdID) as c2
 from Orderrouter a 
 group by a.OrdItems
) TopMost
Order By C2 DESC
```

Comment: Did you test this?  Your second query will fail in sql server.

Comment: Because of the Order By in subquery - I actually did the two queries in part

Comment: You cannot have an `ORDER BY` in a subquery

Answer (score 4):

Any fields that you have in the `SELECT` that are not included in an aggregate function must be in a `GROUP BY`:

```
Select Max(TBLvirtual.c2) as MOF --> Most ordered food (MOF)--// 
    ,TBLvirtual.c1 
from 
(
    select a.OrdItems as c1 , 
        count(a.OrdID)as c2 
    from Orderrouter a 
    group by a.OrdItems
) as TBLvirtual
group by TBLvirtual.c1  -- add this line
```

If you only want one row (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39e91/2)):

```
Select Top 1 c1, c2
from 
(
    select a.OrdItems as c1 , 
        count(a.OrdID)as c2 
    from Orderrouter a 
    group by a.OrdItems
) as TBLvirtual
order by c2 desc
```

And you don't really need the derived table:

```
Select Top 1 
    a.OrdItems as c1 , 
    count(a.OrdID) as c2 
from Orderrouter a 
group by a.OrdItems
order by c2 desc ;
```

Comment: I tried your answer ,however the result wasn't my anticipate result because as you can see I'm looking for the Max row in my table so, at the end it should return me just a row not bunch of rows.

Comment: Actually I need it's "TBLvirtual.c1" for doing the inner join with another table ,so I need both of these column but in one row result .

Comment: @ypercube thanks for the edit, obviously my brain wasn't working. :)